# Is feedforward used in boost converter operating in DCM mode?

Tags: pwm, boost, control-system

Is feedforward used in boost converter operating in DCM mode?
I saw some examples where feedforward is used to control boost converter in CCM but not DCM mode. So I am wondering if it can be used in DCM mode.
Thank you.

Here is an example of boost converter operating in CCM using feedforward:

[image]

Link: [page 143](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=y0FfCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=%22feedforward%22%20%22boost%20converter%22%20%22ccm%22&source=bl&ots=4xlrFCxFpD&sig=eKW3ChaNMYfqjawT9wTVRFCcirE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22feedforward%22%20%22boost%20converter%22%20%22ccm%22&f=false)

Comment: If you provide a link to those examples using feedforward then you have a higher chance of getting an answer. I know my switching converters but have no idea about these using feedforward.

Comment: great book! getting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's a very generic diagram that appears to miss the point IMHO. Sure, if there were another loop (not shown above) that controlled duty cycle based on changing load conditions then, using feed-forward to reduce duty cycle when input supply voltage rises becomes sensible. This won't matter if you're are running continuous or discontinuous.

If you had a synchronous buck converter then the output voltage is (across a vast range of loads) directly proportional to input voltage and duty cycle. For a regulator like this it makes sense to employ feed-forward to control duty cycle based solely on input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The only "control" in this circuit is that the DutyCyle of the switch is somewhat related to the input voltage. This would only work properly if you would have a fixed load. If you remove the load, the output voltage can increase until something breaks. That is not "proper control" in my opinion.

This is a CCM or continous mode or PWM  (Pulse width modulation) converter meaning it keeps switching all the time.

You could operate it in DCM or discontinous mode or PFM (Pulse frequency modulation) **but** during the off period (when it is not switching) the output voltage will drop. When it drops below a certain level the switching has to start again. But how do you know when to start switching again ? There's no feedback. So although I think it is **possible** to operate this converter in DCM/PFM I do not think it is very practical.

In a **proper converter** so including voltage feedback. It would be sensed when the output voltage is getting too low in DCM/PFM. The reason why some converters can switch between CCM and DCM is to save power when the load sometimes requires a high current (we use CCM) but sometimes requires a low current, then we use DCM to save power.

In my opinion this *feedforward* is more a theoretical example and not something you would encounter in a real design. In that respect CCM or DCM does not really matter that much.